# $G$ abelian $p$-group, $x \in G$ of max order. Then cosets in $G/\langle x \rangle$ have represetatives with same order

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is problem 3 from Hungerford's section 2.2. It is not homework, just studying. In full, the statement is:

"Suppose $G$ is a finite abelian $p$-group and $x \in G$ has maximal order. If $\overline{y} \in G/\langle x \rangle$ has order $p^r$, then there is a representative $y \in G$ of the coset $\overline{y}$ such that $|y| = p^r$. Hint: if $|x| = p^t$, then $p^t G = 0$."

Here is my attempt at a proof, but I think there is something missing.

We can write $G = \mathbb{Z}_{p_1^{n_1}} \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p_k^{n_k}}$, and since $G$ is a $p$-group, it must be that $p_1 = \ldots = p_k = p$. WLOG, assume $n_k$ is the largest exponent. Then it must be that $|x| = p^{n_k}$, since all elements of $G$ divide $|x|$ (proved this in an earlier problem), and all elements have order a power of $p$. $|x|$ kills everything in $G$, and so does $p^{n_k}$ (so $|x| \mid p^{n_k}$ and vice versa, thus equality holds)

Then $G = \mathbb{Z}_{p^{n_1}} \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p^{n_{k-1}}} \oplus \langle x \rangle$ and so $G/\langle x \rangle = \mathbb{Z}_{p^{n_1}} \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p^{n_{k-1}}}$.

If $\overline{y} \in G/\langle x \rangle$ has order $p^r$, it has an isomorphic image in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{n_1}} \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p^{n_{k-1}}}$ of order $p^r$, call it $y$.

Then $(y,0)$ (meaning append a $0$ so that it now lies in $G$) in $G$ has order $p^r$ too. I think this is a coset representative of $\overline{y}$, but I do not know how to show it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is just Lemma 8.3 from S.Lang, *Algebra*, Springer, 3rd ed., 2002.

**Addendum:**
Page 43: **Lemma 8.3.** Let $b$ be an element of $A/A_1$, of period $p^r$. Then there exists a 
representative $a$ of $\bar{b}$ in  $A$ which also has period $p^r$.

Here $A_1$ is the subgroup generated by an element of maximal order.

Comment: Do you have a page reference? Or rather, which section 8 it from?

Comment: I added the answer.

Comment: In that proof, why does it follow that $b$ has order $p^{r + r_1 - k}$?

Comment: $p^rb=p^kx$ where $x=\mu a_1$ is an element of order $p^{r_1}$. Hence $|p^rb|=p^{r_1-k}$ and $|b|=p^{r+r_1-k}$.

Comment: Took me awhile to get through it, but I figured it out. Thank you.